# estoy creando una orden de cart, pero al momento del pedido obtengo el error de (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django

mi checkout.py
al momento de ir al checkout obtengo el error, estoy usando un print para ver los datos enviados a consola, pero el user aparece como none y no se como solucionarlo
he estado buscando el error en la session pero no he podido encontrarlo, si alguien puede ayudarme con alguna sugerencia, soy nuevo en django y estoy usando la version 4.0.2

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from django.views import View
    from user.models import User
    from orders.models import Order
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    
    from product.models import Product
    
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
    
    
    class Checkout(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    
        def post (self, request):
            addres = request.POST.get('addres')
            comment = request.POST.get('comment')
            cart = request.session.get('cart')
            user= request.session.get('user')
            product = Product.get_product_by_id(cart)
            print(addres, comment, User, cart, product )
    
    
            for product in product:
    
                print(cart.get(str(product.id)))
    
                order = Order(user_id=user,
                          product=product,
                          price=product.price,
                          addres=addres,
                          comment=comment,
                          quantity=cart.get(str(product.id))["quantity"])
    
                order.save()
    
            request.session['cart'] = {}
    
    
            return redirect ('cart:cart_detail')
```

mi modelo de user el cual fue modificado con el AbstractUser, tome partes de tutoriales que he ido realizando para completar la operación, pero no he podido dar con este error +[image: imagen del error que me aparece]

```
from enum import unique
from statistics import mode
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from limpiaC.settings import MEDIA_URL, STATIC_URL




class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    

class User(AbstractUser):


    identification = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_uploads/', blank=True, 
    null=True,default='images/defaultProfile.jpg')
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, related_name='genders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dateofbirth = models.DateField

    def get_image(self):
        if self.image:
            return '{}{}'.format(MEDIA_URL, self.image)
        return '{}{}'.format(STATIC_URL, 'images/defaultProfile.jpg')
```

```
codigo de modelo order 

class Order(models.Model):


user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
addres = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
comment = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)




def placeOrder(self):
    self.save()

codigo del tutorial

class CheckOut(View):
def post(self, request):
    address = request.POST.get('address')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    customer = request.session.get('customer')
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    products = Product.get_products_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
    print(address, phone, customer, cart, products)

    for product in products:
        print(cart.get(str(product.id)))
        order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer),
                      product=product,
                      price=product.price,
                      address=address,
                      phone=phone,
                      quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))
        order.save()
    request.session['cart'] = {}

    return redirect('cart')
```

el tutorial lo estoy haciendo específicamente de un vídeo de YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkIz1FXpORI&list=PLdBwVRHjcI__NWxctXUSLz1Gg2Mb-B-O-&index=52) precisamente el del enlace

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe ser que el usuario no esta guardado en la sesión, al momento de hacer esto:

```
user= request.session.get('user')
```

Si no existe la llave 'user' en la sesión te almacena un None y tu modelo Order requiere forzosamente un user.

Puedes verificar imprimiendo la variable user antes de hacer el guardado y ver que si esta almacenado.

Si puedes comparte como estas almacenando la sesión para mejorar la respuesta.

Comment: yo estoy haciendo la parte del order de un tutorial pero ya tenia hecho el cart y la session anteriormente, no he podido encontrar en donde esta almacenando la session de user

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código ahí con bloques de código ya que de esta manera no es legible y si puedes añade en donde estas siguiendo el tutorial.

Comment: Lo siento, ya edité la pregunta y añadí el código y el código del tutorial junto con el vídeo de donde lo estoy viendo